# Download data from Google webmaster tools API

Tags: php, google-search-console

Could anyone provide an example or link on how to export `TOP_QUERIES` from Google webmaster tools API?

There are no examples in the repository and there seems to be no available tutorial/example anywhere

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

This code connects to Webmaster Tools.. How to download the `TOP_QUERIES` from a specific date interval?

## code

```
require_once 'googleapi/autoload.php';

try{
    $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        '262251945544-20r941rab6leiuo21ph7ielemtrcsmai@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
        [Google_Service_Webmasters::WEBMASTERS_READONLY],
        file_get_contents('9f21d103bb56.p12')
    );
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()){
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    }
    
    $service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
    $t = $service->sites->get('https://example.com/');
    print_r($t);
}
catch(Google_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
catch(Google_Service_Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: None of the given example show the usage of OAuth in the same way you are. This one is close: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php - It uses a Client ID and uses that when creating the token.

Comment: This example shows just the apiKey: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-query.php and has a good error check , might want to add that in.

Comment: The last link you posted is the one I try in my question..

Comment: That example does not define any OAuth. So I am confused by what you're trying to do. Please clarify.

Comment: I found out that it was the wrong credentials I was using (OAuth).. Have now created a Public API access.. But still get the same error `Login Required`

Comment: [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_apikeys) says you cant use "API Key Authentication" to retrieve user data. `This will not give permissions to retrieve user data, but will allow access to APIs which have been configured for that project.`

Comment: How can I retrieve data from Webmaster tools then?

Comment: You need to use [OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app)

Comment: Have updated my question.. Now I get a new error.. The JSON auth file is invalid..

Comment: I have a complete working example with a link to a step-by-step guide in my answer below. It uses a .p12 auth key instead (per recommendation from their docs). It works and we use it daily at work.

Answer (score 1):

After this line

```
    $service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);
```

add this

```
$searchanalytics = $webmastersService->searchanalytics;
$request = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
$request->setStartDate('2016-03-01'); // startdate required 
$request->setEndDate('2016-03-31');  // Enddate required 
$dimensions[] = 'query';
$request->setDimensions($dimensions);
```

Than Replace this line

```
$results = $service->searchanalytics->query( $url, $search, $options )->getRows();
```

by

```
$results = $searchanalytics->query('site_URL', $request);
```

its work for Us ..... :)

Comment: This is exactly the info I was looking for all over the palce. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Error calling GET
https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F: (404)
'https://example.com/'
```

is not a verified Webmaster Tools site in this account.

The site does not start with `http://`, it starts with `www.example.com` or `example.com`. No trailing slashes either.

```
$t = $service->sites->get('example.com');
```

https://api.kdyby.org/class-Google_Service_Webmasters_SitesListResponse.html

Try those snippets:

```
<?php
$sites = $service->sites->listSites();
print_r(json_encode($sites->toSimpleObject());
```

or

```
<?php
$sites = $service->sites->listSites();
foreach ($sites as $site) {
    print_r($site);
}
```

Comment: No.. Its copy/pasted directly from webmaster tools

Comment: No. Google only allows a DOMAIN, not an URL.

Comment: No matter how I type the site the error is returned.. If I call `$t = $service->sites->listSites();` it seems to return an amtpy object

Comment: Still no site is returned.. :-/

Comment: hehe.. I had to add permissions to the email `262251945544-20r941rab6leiuo21ph7ielemtrcsmai@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.. Now it works.. But can you then tell me how to retreive the `TOP_QUERIES` according to the original question?

Comment: No its not possible via API. All available endpoints are listet here https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sitemaps and mainly concern sitemap indexing and crawling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your Application setup correctly, here's an example of the approach I took:

```
// Authenticate through OAuth 2.0
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    '1111111111-somebigemail@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
    [Google_Service_Webmasters::WEBMASTERS_READONLY],
    file_get_contents( 'path-to-your-key.p12' )
);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials( $credentials );
if ( $client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired() ) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);

// Setup our Search Analytics Query object
$search = new Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
$search->setStartDate( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '1 month ago' ) ) );
$search->setEndDate( date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'now' ) ) );
$search->setDimensions( array( 'query' ) );
$search->setRowLimit( 50 );

// Pass our Search Analytics Query object as the second param to our searchanalytics query() method
$results = $service->searchanalytics->query( $url, $search, $options )->getRows();

// Build a CSV
if ( ! empty( $results ) ) {
    // Setup our header row
    $csv = "Rank,Query,Clicks,Impressions,CTR,Position\r\n";
    foreach ( $results as $key => $result ) {
        // Columns
        $columns = array(
            $key + 1,
            $result->keys[0],
            $result->clicks,
            $result->impressions,
            round( $result->ctr * 100, 2 ) . '%',
            round( $result->position, 1 ),
        );
        $csv .= '"' . implode( '","', $columns ) . '"' . "\r\n";
    }
    file_put_contents( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/data.csv' );
}
```

I have a full article I just posted on my blog that has an example class I started to write as a wrapper for both Webmaster Tools API and Analytics API. Feel free to use this as a reference:

http://robido.com/php/a-google-webmaster-tools-api-php-example-using-search-analytics-api-to-download-search-analytics-data-as-csv-with-the-new-oauth-2-0-method/

Comment: What are the values / parameters in `$options`? @jphase